# How to detect when VideoView starts playing (Android)?

Tags: android, events, android-videoview

Here's the problem, I want to change play button to pause button when the video stream starts playing in videoview but I don't know how to detect that event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using VideoView.setOnPreparedListener. This was enough to cover my problem (play button drawable change to pause)

Answer (score 22):

There is a great article about MediaPlayer in here - http://www.malmstein.com/blog/2014/08/09/how-to-use-a-textureview-to-display-a-video-with-custom-media-player-controls/

You can set infoListener on your VideoView

```
setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START) {
            // Here the video starts
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it requres API > 16

Comment: the link is broken here

Answer (score 11):

accepted answer here is not 100% accurate.

sometimes onprepared is call 3 seconds before first frame is being rendered. i suggest having a callback on that event (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        if (i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START){
            //first frame was bufered - do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

see media info documantaion for more callbacks of info/warning:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no event sent when video start playing in VideoView, but I can think of two options:

1. Create a version of VideoView by yourself, that sends event in those cases.
2. Use MediaController (which is default in VideoView)

If you want to follow option one - you can get the source of [VideoView from here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java)

Answer (score -1):

isPlaying() can be called to test whether the MediaPlayer object is in the Started

[Android MediaPlayer.isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to detect if videoview started is using videoView.getCurrentPosition(). **getCurrentPosition()** returns 0 if streaming not started.

```
    protected Runnable playingCheck = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (vw.getCurrentPosition() != 0) {
                    // do what you want when playing started
                    break;
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Then call:

```
new Thread(playingCheck).start();
```

Comment: OMG, please don't go this way! You're polling with a while(true). This is really bad.

Comment: I agree with @edoardotognoni

Comment: the key point of the answer is not the loop part, but the getCurrentPosition() method. I just wanted to call this function periodically to detect if the video is started or not. you can use different structures for periodic operations if you want. but like i said, it is not the important part of "is my video started" problem

Comment: and i will be so glad if you state what should i use instead of while(true), please.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            if (videoView.getCurrentPosition() != 0) {
                                ((ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pgStreaming)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                h.postDelayed(this, 250);
                            }
                    }
                }, 250);
```