# Android Service to detect video playback on a third party Video Player

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-service, playback

I need to develop an Android Service (API level > 21), which should be able to detect video playback on a third party Video player, so that it can further disable the Notification pop-ups during a video playback.

On searching, I found several posts talking about detecting the play-states of videos in a VideoView, such as the following:
[How to detect when VideoView starts playing (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529572/how-to-detect-when-videoview-starts-playing-android)

But, I couldn't  find anything that can help detecting video playback on a video player, wherein, the video player is installed as a third party app and is not a part of the Android application/ service.

So, the challenges are:

1) The android service needs to detect a video playback

2) Registering package names for video player apps with the Service is out of question, since the Service should be able to detect the playback even when a new video player is installed from the Playstore.

3) Need to extend this idea for online video streaming as well.

Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement 100% reliable video playback detection :(

Just and idea: try listening to the audio focus changes... this might help with detection of video playback, assuming the target player respects the audio output stream usage policy, recommended by Google. You might also want to get notified about system UI visibility changes (to detect fullscreen playback).

Audio focus:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html

System UI visibility changes:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

Also, you are correct saying that package name based detector is not an option since detecting active/running package is no longer possible on android 7.

Comment: Just listening to Audio Focus changes and System UI visibility changes might not suffice the problem statement. The android service can misinterpret other scenarios (like gallery browsing in full screen with mp3 playback in the background; or, gaming) with Video playback, if we consider these two as the determining factors. Please correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: Also, can you please help me out regarding the implementation of OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener for a third party video player??