# How to calculate Time To First Frame (TTFF) in Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I have written a simple app in Android that uses `MediaPlayer` API to play a video from a URL. How to calculate **Time To First Frame (TTFF)**?

Here is my snippet:

```
        String url ="http://192.168.174.80/video-h264.mkv";
        //.....
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        vw1.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        // Listener for onPrepared() event (runs after the media is prepared).
        vw1.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { 
                        // Start playing!
                        vw1.start();

                        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                                    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    mBufferingTextView.setText((t1 - t0) + " ms,  %" + i + " buffer");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you saying the `onBufferingUpdate` is not enough to detect if first frame is displayed? Would listening to a video time change/progress event be more useful to measure _"How much time for some playback to happen"_?.. Also this might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527417/2057709

Comment: Onbufferipdate() is called on different percentages. It's not deterministic. What I did is calculate the time right after vw1.start()

Comment: OK. I thought `vw.start()` was a starting a process that included _beginning of_ getting video data (bytes) from URL. I thought you wanted to measure time going from first request to server (to get the first http packet) up to when first frame is displayed to user. I see now that the `start` happens after _"media is prepared"_ (I assume that's meaning when some buffered video amount is ready to play). Maybe the best way here is to measure time from when `start` is triggered up to when the video has a change in time (_eg:_ 1 second of video time progresses).

Comment: PS: I don't use Android SDK so make sure  _"`onPrepared() event (runs after the media is prepared)`"_  is when the media is partly / fully buffered and ready for playback. If it just means the video object itself is ready to begin (_eg:_ loading) then you _don't_ have any media prepared for playback yet. Also did checking for `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START` work for you (as mentioned in my link above)?

Comment: Didn't try that yet. Right now my t1 is after vm start() and visually, as soon as the video is played, it prints the number. It may not be exact, but is a good estimate probably. Can you please write the correct code of what u mean?